# how to limit the number of sessions connected

Tags: php, session, limit

I've written a script in order to limited the number of session into my area.

So We have the following code:

```
if ( $d = opendir( session_save_path()  )  ) {
        $count = 0;
        $session_timeout = 3*600;
        while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $d )  )  ) {
            if ( $file != '.' && $file != '..' ) {
                if ( time()- fileatime(session_save_path() . '/' . $file) < $session_timeout ) {
                      $count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if($count>$societe['max_utilisateurs'])
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO `session` SET
`temps` = now(),
`login`='".$_SESSION['login']."',
`mouvement`='2'";  
mysql_query($sql) or die;
session_unset();  
session_destroy();  
header('Location: ../');  
exit();  
    };
```

The trouble is that when I echo $count it display 2. But the thing is that I'm the only user that is online. I've limited in mysql the number of connexions, and I do compare this number to the number of session, but the number of session is actualy false.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This won't really work as it stands; this code implies that you are calling `session_start` unconditionally, whereas that is exactly what you should not be doing (instead of trying to clean up afterwards).

Comment: Sorry But I do not understand. I have a session start at the top of my page

Comment: This looks a lot like the kind of work that PHP does internally, so there should be no reason to do this. What's the real problem here?

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Instead of calling `session_start` and then cleaning up, do the check *first* and *do not* call `session_start` if you shouldn't.

Comment: so You mean I need to call first that code instead of making a session start?